# Pinging computer on a different network

Tags: ipv6, ping

I would like to know if it is possible to ping a computer on a different network using ipv6. If I am understanding it correctly then IPV6 was created for each device to have its unique ip address. Following that logic even on my local area network each device must have a unique ipv6 address that could be reached from anywhere. Am i wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Why not? Google is on a different network and I ping that all the time.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

If both computers have a global  IPv6 addresses(from the 2000::/3 prefix), IPv6 routing is correct and nothing blocks traffic (e.g. a firewall or a router access list) this ist true.

The same is true for IPv4 networks using only public IPv4 addresses.